# How to call user variables in Django ModelAdmin

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-admin, django-modeladmin

I am new to Django and having trouble understanding how to call proper variables in a `ModelAdmin`. If I am on `/admin/mt_app/my_model/` that I have information like the user's name OR I'm on `/admin/auth/user/2/change/` that has all the user's information, how do I call those variables in the ModelAdmin View?

I got it working selectively by plugging in my own user, but I can't figure out how to call the relevant user or model from the view. All I can find is how to call the current user, but again, I need the user of the that the page is regarding, not the active user. Ex: `/admin/algorx/pt_data/41/change/` or `/admin/auth/user/2/change/`

What I have now is:

**Admin.py**

```
class pt_dataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = (
       . . .
    )

 # This gets passed into change_view as extra context
    def get_dynamic_info(self):
        user = User.objects.get(email='MYSUPERUSEREMAIL')
        return user
        . . .
    
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        . . .
```

So what works is passing in my super user's email to select that user:

```
        user = User.objects.get(email='MYSUPERUSEREMAIL')
        return user
```

But what I want to do is select the user of the current page being viewed. If I'm on the following URL how do I select that user's variable?
`/admin/auth/user/2/change/`

I see many SO questions about selecting the current user, but I want to know how to select the user being viewed. Any help would be appreciated, this has now been a 2 day roadblock for my novice-self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending two days in stackoverflow hell, I pieced together the answer!

First, I added a field to my model that contains the user who created it:

**MODELS.PY:**

```
pt_user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then, I added

**ADMIN.PY**

```
@admin.register(pt_data)
class pt_dataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = (
         . . . )

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        pt_model = pt_data.objects.get(id=object_id)
        user = pt_model.pt_user
        loglink = get_query_string(user)
        extra_context['osm_data'] = {'link': loglink}
        # extra_context['osm_data'] = self.get_dynamic_info()
        return super(pt_dataAdmin, self).change_view(
            request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context,
        )
```

This let me query the object_id of the URL to find the model in the database, then from the model extract the user. The `get_query_string` is from a package called Sesame that creates a magic login link for users to login without a password. I return this to my `chage_view` as `extra_context` so I can call it on the template as `{{ osm_data.link }}`